# Pandas function runs slower on multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, python-multithreading

I have some Python code that uses `pandas`, which takes about half a second to run. When I call the main function 5 times serially (on a single thread), each call takes about half a second, so that's 2.5 seconds total. However, when I call this function on 5 different threads, each run takes 2.5 seconds (which is also 2.5 seconds total, but I would expect it to be only half a second total, because the threads run in parallel).

The code essentially does this (simplified for the sake of brevity):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandsas as pd

def build_df():
    event_type_0_lst = {'a': 1, 'b':{'c': 2}}
    event_type_1_lst = {'d': 4, 'e':{'f': 5}}
    event_type_2_lst = {'g': 7, 'h':{'i': 8}}
    type_0_df = pd.DataFrame()
    type_1_df = json_normalize(event_type_1_lst)
    type_1_df[self.event_source_col] = self.event_type_1
    type_2_df = json_normalize(event_type_2_lst)
    type_2_df[self.event_source_col] = self.event_type_2
    all_data_df = pd.concat([type_0_df, type_1_df, type_2_df])
    final_df = all_data_df[
                        [self.ticket_col, self.timestamp_col, self.trigger_col, self.action_col,
                         self.action_uid_col, self.msg_id_col, self.flc_col, self.event_source_col]]
    final_df[self.timestamp_col] = pd.to_datetime(final_df[self.timestamp_col])
    return ticket_df.sort_values(self.timestamp_col).reset_index(drop=True)

def normalize(df):
    df.columns = [col.replace('.', '_') for col in df.columns]
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
        df[col] = df[col].str.encode('unicode-escape').replace('\\x', '<repl>')
        df[col] = df[col].str.encode('unicode-escape').replace('\n', '<repl>')
    return df


def handle_request():
    df = build_df()
    return normalize(df)
```

The function `handle_request` can be called from a web server (using the ThreadPoolExecutor of the `concurrent.futures` package) or from a standalone python script (using the `threading` package with the standard method of Thread creation), and the issue is reproduced on both cases. The machine on which I run this function has 8 cores, which should be enough for 5 threads.

When I run this function, I get the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
FutureWarning: sort(columns=....) is deprecated, use sort_values(by=.....)
  df_sorted = df.sort(col_order_by, ascending=True)
```

I don't think it has any relevance to the issue, but I pasted it just in case it does.

So, why does each run take ~2.5 seconds instead of ~0.5?

EDIT: This is how I run the function with `threading`:

```
threads_list = []
for i in range(num_of_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=handle_request)
    threads_list.append(t)

for t in threads_list:
    t.start()
```

I tried adding:

```
for t in threads_list:
    t.join()
```

But it didn't seem to have any influence on the performance.

Comment: There will be an overhead associated with starting and monitoring the threads - it's possible that this is a factor. You've also not provided an example of how your are setting up the parallel runs, and there may be some inefficiencies in that.

Comment: I edited the original question and added the description of how I run the function using the `threading` package. The behavior is reproduced even when I try to run it using 10 threads (that is, it takes ~5 seconds to run), so I don't think it has to do with the thread-starting overhead. Moreover, I tried replacing the called function (handle_request) with a function that only calls `sleep(0.5)`, and the behavior does not occur: all threads return after half a second.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, as described in detail in [this blog post](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Parallelising-Python-with-Threading-and-Multiprocessing/), "Python on the CPython interpreter does not support true multi-core execution via multithreading."

Instead of using the `threading` library, use the `multiprocessing` library.  In the example below, all I did was replace your code with calls to the `multiprocessing` library.  There are some caveats to this approach, however; you will need to manage communication between the processes using utilities meant to work with the `multiprocessing` library.  (I have made good use of the `multiprocessing.Queue` class, for instance.)

```
import multiprocessing

processes_list = []
for _ in range(num_of_processes):
    processes_list.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=handle_request))

for p in processes_list:
    p.start()
```